# Compute Product Python General formula

Tags: python

Trying to get this to post the following 3 lines as a result.  Nothing more, nothing less.

1. The product of the numbers `1` through `10` is: `3628800`
2. The product of the first `3` numbers divisible by `3` is: `162`
3. The product of the numbers `0` through `-100` is: `0`

Start is where the sequence starts, number is where it ends, and space is the space between the numbers (`1` is every number, `2` is even numbers only, etc).

I am a beginner to this, and need some assistance

This is what I have s far, but I'm not sure what to define findproduct as.  I was thinking something along the lines of making a loop and setting `n =` to `n+1` but I still have no idea where to take this:

```
def findproduct(start, number, space):
    # code here
    pass

product1 = findproduct(1, 10, 1)
print("The product of the numbers 1 through 10 is:", product1)

product2 = findproduct (2.0, 5, 2)
print("The product of the first 5 even numbers is:", product2)

product3 = findproduct (3, 3, 3)
print("The product of the first 3 numbers divisible by 3 is:", product3)

product4 = findproduct (0.0, 100, -1)
print("The product of the numbers -1 through -100 is:", product4)
```

Comment: Look up the [range function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range). It will give you what you want.

Comment: it's not a homework, I'm just trying to get comfortable with python.  We've learned how to define stuff, and I just wanna try to get something of my own to work.

one could say it's my own homework

Comment: @solarc I have that written down in my notes, but I'm not exactly how to incorporate it into what I want

Answer (score 0):

`range` gets you the numbers you need given the `start`, `stop` and `step`. Your `stop`s appear to be inclusive (where `range` is exclusive on `stop`) so you'd need to adjust, but that's not too hard:

```
def inclusive_range(start, stop, step):
    if step < 0:
        stop -= 1
    else:
        stop += 1
    return range(start, stop, step)
```

That gets you the set of numbers you want the product of. You can do this the obvious way with an accumulator loop:

```
def find_product(start, stop, step):
    prod = 1
    for i in inclusive_range(start, stop, step):
        prod *= i
    return prod
```

or get clever with built-ins to one-line it (ignoring imports at the top of the file):

```
 from functools import reduce
 from operator import mul

def find_product(start, stop, step):
    return reduce(mul, inclusive_range(start, stop, step), 1)
```

The spelled out loop has some mild advantages; you could add a test to it for `prod == 0` and break out of the loop early should that occur; if a zero appears anywhere in the input, you're not going to end up with a non-zero product anyway. Of course, in Python 3, where `range` is a more powerful object, you could pre-check for 0 in the `range` and avoid the work even more efficiently:

```
def find_product(start, stop, step):
    values = inclusive_range(start, stop, step)        
    if 0 in values:
        return 0
    return reduce(mul, values, 1)
```